# How can we find the singularities of the function?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$F=y^2-x^2-x^3$

We have find the singularities of the function, the folds and the equations of the tangent lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a cubic curve, so it has at most $\;\dfrac{(3-1)(-3-2)}2=1$ singular point. Now the origin is an ordinary double point and the two tangents have equation 
$$x^2-y^2=0.$$